# default styles in dynamicaly generated TextViews

Tags: android, css, colors, default

When I'm adding textviews to xml layout files I get textviews with black text color by default;
When I'm generating this textviews programmatically I get textviews with a kind of gray text color.
I want this text views have the same style, and I'm not sure whether simple setting black color for dynamically generated textviews will help, because I'm not sure it will look the same on all versions of android.
What will you recommend me? What style resource is default?

Isn't there any possibilities of using default styles?

Answer (score 0):

Set the colors your self either in the xml

```
android:textColor="#000000"
```

or dynamically

```
mText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

I never use the default colors

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a default style in styles.xml. Create an item with text color black or the default color you want to use.

You can also refer this site: 
http://androidplus.org

Answer (score 0):

I guess what your looking for is `android.R.color.primary_text_light` which is the default color for dark text in a light theme like in your case.

```
int c = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.primary_text_light);
textView.setTextColor(textColor);
```

It may be even better to use `android.R.attr.textColorPrimary` as it returns the appropriate default color for both themes:

```
int[] attrs = new int[] {android.R.attr.textColorPrimary};
TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);
int textColor = ta.getColor(0, Color.BLACK);
ta.recycle();

textView.setTextColor(textColor);
```